# Is snap verified by Ubuntu SnapCraft Team?

Tags: permissions, snap, malware

Is snap verified by Ubuntu SnapCraft Team similar like Apple in Appstore?

Verification about: It contains malware / spyware / virus / stealing information / unnecessary permission usage or not.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not like Appstore.

Anybody can publish an unreviewed snap at any time, and that snap might contain malware.

It's **up to you** to install snaps only from trusted authors. In Deb-based Ubuntu, it's similarly up to you to choose only trustworthy software sources - Ubuntu does nothing to check PPAs and other common non-Ubuntu sources.

However:

1. The design of Snaps is built around preventing rogue applications from running through your system, stealing data and causing damage.

   A malicious Snap package can cause you some headache...but much less than a malicious Deb package (which includes preinst/postinst scripts that run as root!)
2. If you discover a malicious Snap, go the the Snap Store page for that snap and report it ("*Is there a problem with <name>? Report this app*").

   One malicious snap was indeed discovered -- in 2019, if I recall correctly. It was reported, and promptly investigated and removed. Feel free to get involved and test snaps for trustworthiness!

Answer (score 1):

When someone creates a snap package, they can get it added to the Snap Store.
Only if the snap package is using the `strict` confinement, which does not have full access to your system.

Still, though, a malicious snap package can be malicious, but
1. Cannot look into any .dot files and directories in your home directory.
2. Only has access to your home folder, it it has been configured to access the home.
3. Does not have access to `/tmp/`. It gets only a private tmp, which is separate from any other applications.

If a developer wants to add more privileges to their snap package, they have to request it at the forum.snapcraft.io forum. It will get accepted on a case by case basis.

Still, only install packages from reputable sources, and those that have been downloaded by many, many, others. See, for example, the download map at https://snapcraft.io/vlc

Comment: Thank you, user4124. You have also knowledgeable information. ️️